# Add the "Insufficient information" banner when new users are answering a question for the first time

Tags: feature-request, answers, new-users, welcoming

I think a good idea to help new users be more accustomed to the site would be to add the "Insufficient information" banner when they click "Answer this question" and they haven't answered a question before.

Here's the text from the banner:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

I think this applies to all answers (especially ones written by new users), and so may be helpful to someone answering a question for the first time.

Could we add this?

For clarity, the banner should show up above the "Your answer" box while the user is writing the answer if the user hasn't answered a question before.

Answer (score 20):

I mentioned something similar [a few years back during the 2nd iteration of the SE Quality Project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285924/311398), which never saw the light of the day. I tried to cover all the different possible cases in my answer there. Anyway, repeating myself partially ...

The problem isn't that the new users are knowingly adding bad answers. The problem is that the new users have no idea what a good answer is. The thing that new users see is:

> [image]

which is very similar to the license agreement that we all are so accustomed to click OK, and move ahead.

There is no information there regarding:

1. Non Answers
2. Link Only Answers
3. Code Only Answers
4. Plagiarism

Ironically, there is a link to the tips on writing great answers page, but how many of the users have the time/patience to go to that page? A gist of the information present on that page must be made readily available on the same page, or atleast hidden behind a simple collapse menu.

Adding the post notice is just too late. The deed has already been committed. There are many many users who just post their answer, close the tab and move on. Take the common NAAs as an example. There are users who constantly post the "This does not provide an answer ..." auto comment, but how many users have self-deleted their post? It is just a handful. (I do know the issue with unregistered users trying to delete their post, but not being able to, [that is also a SE Quality Project Iteration II Request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285898/311398), but let's just set that aside for now). Post Notices or even auto comments rarely help in making the users aware of what is a valid answer or what is not. The Post Notice text itself is insufficient. We need better mechanisms that solve the issue at the root.

Finally, there's the problem with users who are aware of answering on Stack Overflow, due to their experience on other Stack Exchange sites. The post notice would be quite useless in those cases.

I don't want to dismiss your idea, it is a really good one, but the problem that we need to solve is that we need to provide  the answerers with sufficient information before hand. A compromise would be to add post notices to only those answers that are smaller than a given length, consist of just one sentence or something similar. But again, any of these techniques are just like band-aids and aren't going to be that fruitful. What we need is a "Post Answer Wizard" of sorts. Well, we did get a "Ask Question Wizard" after almost half a decade, let's hope that answer improvements are also in the pipeline.

Comment: Improving the answer guidance is a great idea. And thanks for linking your post from a few years back regarding the SE Quality Project Iteration II--I hadn't seen it yet. Understanding what underlies the volume of NAA flags and ways to address this is very much on my mind, so this is helpful.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks for looking into it!